# Setting up python env for development and debugging in nixos

Tags: python, debugging, nixos, pythoninterpreter, nix-shell

I have jumped the ship from arch to nixos and for compatibility with my server I am sticking with stable channel and using home-manager, yet to try flakes!!

Setting up python environment has been the biggest deterrent to completely shift to nixos, and I need some help on the same.

In arch I use conda to manage my environments for development and once it is production ready I use pdm to lock the environments and reproduce it in the server.

In nixos, I setup conda-shell but I am unable to set the conda envs as python interpreters in pycharm/vscode, conda paths are needed for **debugging**, secondly I can temporarily create a nix-shell with pdm and install necessary packages JIT for running the program, python path set can't read the installed packages so no debug here too, to install new packages I should repeat the cycle and its a hassle.

I need some input from nixos versatiles, how to setup python envs both for development and debugging?

*Note: When I select the conda path (~/.conda/bin/conda) as python interpreter in vscode/pycharm I get an error - `Cannot run program "~/.conda/bin/conda": error =2, No such file or directory`.*

my trial and error :

1. conda-shell
2. virtualenv - refs to nix/store
3. pdm - refs to nix/store if venv is created
4. nix-shell for temporary workaround - debugging is not possible

Expecting:

some ideas on how people setup their python envs, so I could replicate them.

Solution: (Originally posted in reddit, link attached)
https://www.reddit.com/r/NixOS/comments/16431ro/python_and_nixos/jyf6xt1/?context=3